# LM78XX voltage regulators

Tags: voltage-regulator

I am building a cheap bench top power supply for my bread board prototypes using a LM7805.

[image]

I want to know based on the above diagram could I just change in a LM7812? I would like to be able to flick a switch to change between voltages if so. Could the switch just change the input switch or would I need to remove all three connections?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can place the switch on the input of the regulator, and duplicate the regulator and the components after it.
A few remarks, though. The input says `< 24V AC/DC`. I presume this comes from a transformer, so it will be up to 24V AC. Rectified that will be \$24V \times \sqrt{2} - 2V = 32V\$  . That's a lot, and especially the LM7805 will get hot: it would have to dissipate 27W at 1A, that won't do! Choose a transformer in function of the 12V. It will need 15V at the input, so that's 12V AC minimum. Especially the 7805 will still need cooling.
Then 25V for the input electrolytic capacitor is also OK (it wouldn't be for 24V AC!).

All this said, there are much nicer solutions. The [LM317](http://www.national.com/ds/LM/LM117.pdf) is also a three-legger but has a variable output voltage, so if you use a potmeter you can vary the output voltage continuously. If you want you can still use a switch to get 5V or 12V directly: so, a switch 5V-12V-variable.

**edit** (some refinements)
First the input capacitor. For a 1A supply (a minimum value for a bench top supply) the 470\$\mu\$F won't do. My rule-of-thumb is 2000\$\mu\$F/A, so use a 2200\$\mu\$F type. You also want a smaller cap parallel to it to suppress glitches (the 2200\$\mu\$F is not good at this). I would place a 1\$\mu\$F ceramic there.
You mention this application example in your comment:

[image]

The capacitor gives a better ripple rejection. Ripple is the variation which remains after the rectified voltage has been smoothed out by the capacitor:

[image]

The LM317 has already better ripple rejection than the LM78xx, but you get this almost for free, so I would add it.

**edit2** (putting on my product manager's hat)
Especially when you're working with microcontrollers you'll want to have a fixed power supply available for that at any time, apart from the adjustable. Most microcontrollers work at 3.3V or 5V. Probably best thing would be to feed two regulators parallel from the input capacitor: one which can switch between 3.3V and 5V, and one adjustable through a potmeter. The adjustable can then be used for peripherals like small motors and relays.

Comment: I will have a look at the LM317

Comment: @Ashley - let us know if you need help with the switch. I'm not sure I explained clearly.

Comment: Looks like the way to go, just wondering the circuit diagram on the 1st page with the pot replaced with a switch with 2 fixed resistors or build with ripple protection on page 16 as i have some spare 1N4004's lying around? ripple protection = cleaner power?

Comment: @Ashley - Yes, the switch with 2 fixed resistors, but while you're at it, why not a three -position switch with the pot at the third position? Ripple rejection = cleaner power. The ripple comes from the AC input (BTW, use a 2200\$\mu\$F cap on the input!). And a Schottky diode instead of the 1N4002 in the schematic would be better, but a 1N4004 will also work. Success!

Comment: If you're interested I have written a little LM317T resistor calculator here: http://electronics.sqsol.co.uk/calculators/lm317t

Comment: Personally I have an old 1U ATX PSU on my desk for my prototyping work.  It gives me +5V, +3.3V, +12V and -12V - all I ever need.

Comment: The calculator might have taken \$I_{ADJ}\$ into account. I can understand that you ignore it when you're doing the calculation in your head, but from a tool like this I expect it does the calculation right.

Comment: So change C2 to 2200uF dont think i have a cap that big thats not electrolylic

Comment: @Ashley - That's because there *aren't* any that big that are not electrolytic. So you *have* to use one. Make sure it has the right voltage rating (see answer). If you don't have 2200 You can place 2 x 1000 in parallel. And watch the polarity.

Comment: Ok well its built on breadboard for now works well enough, not using all the correct parts at the moment though IE C2 has the two biggest cap's that i have still only 940uF@25v but I wont be taking it near one amp for a while. also had to c3 a non electrolytic but works well enough no black smoke or excess heat. will load up a few LED to see how it handles say 100mA or so for a while. Thanks for your input @stevenvh

Comment: If your input capacitors are a bit too small it's not always disastrous. The ripple over them, and thus at the input of the regulator will be larger, and a small part of it may penetrate through the regulator to the output, so that the regulated voltage isn't perfectly smooth. If the ripple is too big the lowest point may be below the minimum the regulator requires, and you'll have noticeable dips in the 5V. You won't break anything, but may have unwanted effects, like a microcontroller always resetting itself.

Comment: I have defently got some thing wrong some where as placing one LED on with the regulator at around 10v drops the output to around 3v

Comment: @Ashley - you didn't forget to place a series resistor to limit the LED's current, did you?

Comment: that was there, i even tried taking out the LED and the voltage just drops straight off, I will look into it more tomorrow after work and buy the correct value parts

Comment: Edit for above just replace the LED for a few different resistors for load

Comment: This is the circuit that I am using, or thought still haven't had a chance to pull it apart and place back together again. If you could check my values and diagram that would be great image of it at https://files.me.com/ashley.hughes/kwgbz8

Comment: @Ashley - You've either drawn it wrongly, or connected it wrongly, but your R2 is not variable the way it's drawn: you move the wiper (pin 2) over the resistance between pin 1 and pin 3, but you don't do anything with it. Connect the wiper to either pin 1 or pin 3. The rest looks OK.

Comment: Thanks for you help @stevenvh I finally got around to finishing it off, and designed a board for it to go onto in Eagle. https://files.me.com/ashley.hughes/xp8kfi

Answer (score 2):

You can make a variable output voltage regulator using a 7805:
[image: 7805 Circuit]

This Circuit is taken from this [datasheet](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/LM/LM7812.pdf).

Comment: Like it says this circuit won't go all the way down to 5V. That's because the 741's output doesn't go all to the rails. An RRIO (Rail-to-Rail I/O) opamp will solve this, but even then 5V will be the lower limit.

Comment: 1. Use an LM324 or LM358 opamp instead of an LM741. (Very very naughty of Fairchild. The data sheet claims to be 2010 but that circuit was drawn decades ago and an LM741 is a very poor choice. The LM741 needs dual positive and negative power supplies. A negative supply is not directly available here. An LM324 / LM358 is "single supply". Ground V- and use Vinput as V+ for op amp). ...........
2. Change the LM7805 to an LM317 and the circuit will go down to about 1.25 Volt ...........
3. Larger capacitors may be useful. See LM317 data sheet for examples.

Comment: @Russell yeah looking at it again it is a bad design. I did this while half asleep this morning so didn't pay too much attention to it.

Comment: @Russell - yes, an LM324 will work on a single supply, but still isn't rail-to-rail out, so no 5V. I agree with the LM317 (which my answer is based upon).

Comment: 1. Design is OKish - just that op amp shown is very old and is dual supply.
2. Yes - LM324 is not rail to rail but will go extremely close to ground on low side. Maybe add a modest pull down at output as wasting a little power is not going to matter here. You can probably get within a few 10's of mV of ground so Vout would be say >= 5.05V with a 5V regulator and >= 1.3 V with an LM317.

Answer (score 0):

You could put a switch at the output, where you have a switch in the diagram, and connect the inputs in parallel.

I would choose a lower input voltage, otherwise a lot of heat is generated in the voltage regulators and you will need a lot of cooling to get 1A output current.

Note that DC after rectification will be approximately 1.4 times higher than the rated AC voltage, so 25V is not enough for your capacitor.